# Make at least one group mandatory

Tags: java, regex

I have a question about regexes in Java, though I think this might apply to other languages as well.

I have a regex to parse time from a field where user may enter something like `4d 8h 42m`. Of course, I want to make it as flexible as possible, so that user should not be obliged to type all numbers (and enter a mere `15h` for instance).

My regex is quite satisfactory concerning that point: `(?:([\d]+)d)?[\s]*(?:([\d]+)h)?[\s]*(?:([\d]+)m)?`

Now my problem is that it will also match an empty string, though I would like it to ensure that at least one time-unit is filled.

The current solution would be to arbitrary choose one of them to be mandatory, but I am not satisfied with it since mandatory field is what I am trying to avoid.

Also, making an *or* does not suit me, since I would have to test groups when parsing the regex afterwards, instead of just accessing group(1) for days, group(2) for hours, ...
(This is what I think of when speaking of an *or* : `(?:([\d]+)d[\s]*(?:([\d]+)h)?[\s]*(?:([\d]+)m)?|(?:([\d]+)d)?[\s]*([\d]+)h[\s]*(?:([\d]+)m)?|(?:([\d]+)d)?[\s]*(?:([\d]+)h)?[\s]*([\d]+)m)`, to be understood as *days mandatory or hours mandatory or minutes mandatory*).

So how could I modify my regex to make sure that at least one of my now-non-capturing group is not empty, be it days, hours or minutes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a look-forward assert to ensure that at least one of `d` `h` or `m` appears.

```
(?=.*[mhd])(?:(\d+)d)?\s*(?:(\d+)h)?\s*(?:(\d+)m)?
```

Comment: `[]` is useless here..except `[mhd]`

Comment: The look-forward works great! And @Fake.It.Til.U.Make.It, thanks for the cleaning tip too. My new regex then: `(?=.*[mhd])(?:(\d+)d)?\s*(?:(\d+)h)?\s*(?:(\d+)m)?` (well, not mine, actually; I elaborate a little more to allow for space or case errors...)

Answer (score 2):

As OmnipotentEntity suggested, you can use a positive look-ahead to determine if the number(s) are followed by a `d`, `m` or `h`.

Another way of writing it could be:

```
(\d+(?=[dhm])[dhm]\s*){1,3}
```

This would match the following:

```
4d 8h 42m
3d
15h
28m
12d 24m
2h 55m
7d  11h  24m
5d2h5m
```

Comment: This idea would work great, but the access would harder. Using OmnipotentEntity's idea, I know that days = group(1), hours = group(2), ... Here, I must test each. Plus, there is no way to ensure each unit is passed only once. Thanks, though.